# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __DEV__

Tags: react-native

When I launch my project I am getting a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __DEV__` error. I have commented out almost all of my code and now only have this

```
import React, {
    Component,
    Text
} from "react-native";

var {
    AppRegistry
} = React;

class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Text>App</Text>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => Root);
```

I have tried wiping out my `node_modules` folder and doing a clean build from Xcode. The packager console output doesn't show any problems and the Xcode Console is blank. At this point I don't know what else to try.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was having `"strict"` in my `.babelrc` file. It appears that react-native is assigning `__DEV__` without declaring it.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3605

Comment: seeing this despite not having "strict" in the .babelrc

Comment: I agree with @MaxMacLeod, I also see this while not having strict in .babelrc